# Maven - Windows installer plugin

Tags: java, maven

do you know a highly configurable maven plugin for creating MS Windows installers?

The artifacts of my project are processed through a Maven Launch4j plugin, therefore I already have an executable (*.exe) file, but I need to install the other dependencies and resources as well: *.dll, images, the executable and so on. I also like to install the jre (if required), set some environment variables and so on.

Can you recomend a plugin?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [nsis-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/)

> The nsis-maven-plugin enables Maven integration with the NSIS tools so
>   that Windows and Linux build machines can create Windows Installer
>   EXEs.

Comment: Robert, thank you for your answer... I'd like to test this plugin and than accept this answer.